# How does reduce decide its initial value, when it's not provided?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

How does javascript's `reduce` function determine its initial value, when it is not passed? Does it simply default to the number `0`?

Why do these two work:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((sum, currentValue) => {
  return sum + currentValue;
});

[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((string, currentValue) => {
  return `${string}` + currentValue;
});
```

But this doesn't?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((object, currentValue) => {
  object[currentValue] = currentValue;
  return object;
});
```

Comment: It uses the the first value from the array and the first currentValue is the second element of the array.

Comment: Reduce has 2 parameters, the first one a function or callback and the second the initial value

Comment: `If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.` Do *research* before posting questions.

Comment: developer.mozilla explains this very well -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)  initialValue (Optional)

> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.